# Creating a faceted matplotlib/seaborn plot using indicator variables rather than a single column

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Seaborn is great for creating faceted plots based on a categorical variable encoding the class of each facet. However, this assumes your categories are mutually exclusive. Is it possible to create a Seaborn `FacetGrid` (or similar) based on a set of indicator variables?

As a concrete example, think about comparing patients that are infected with one or more viruses, and plotting an attribute of interest by virus. Its possible that a patient carries more than one virus, so creating a `virus` column to create a grid on is not possible. You can, however, create a set of indicator variables (one for each virus) that flags the virus for each patient. There does not seem to be a way of passing a set of indicator variables to any of the Seaborn functions to do this.

[image]

I can't imagine I'm the first person to come across this scenario, so I'm hoping there are suggestions for how to do this, without coding it by hand in Matploltlib.

Comment: So, for instance, adapting the [Seaborn example](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), there might be smokers of tobacco, clove, weed, any combination, or none of these, so there would be four rows of facets (T, C, W, none) and a person's tip behavior might be reported in more than one row?

Comment: Yes, each row could belong to zero, one or more groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how to do it with FacetGrid, possibly because this isn't facetting the data, since a data-record might appear several times or only once in the plot.  One of the standard tricks with a set of bitfields is to read them as binary, so you see each combination of the bits. That's unambiguous but gets messy:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from numpy.random import random, randint
from numpy import concatenate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dummy data
vdata = pd.DataFrame(concatenate((randint(2, size=(32,4)), random(size=(32,2))), axis=1))
vdata.columns=['Species','v1','v2','v3','x','y']
binary_v = vdata.v1 + vdata.v2*2 + vdata.v3*4
# Making a binary number out of the "virusX?" fields 
pd.concat((vdata, binary_v), axis=1)
vdata = pd.concat((vdata, binary_v), axis=1)
vdata.columns=['Species','v1','v2','v3','x','y','binary_v']

# Plotting group membership by row
#g = sns.FacetGrid(vdata, col="Species", row='binary_v')
#g.map(plt.scatter, "x", "y")
#g.add_legend()
#plt.savefig('multiple_facet_binary_row') # Unreadably big. 

h = sns.FacetGrid(vdata, col="Species", hue="binary_v")
h.map(plt.scatter, "x","y")
h.add_legend()
plt.savefig('multiple_facet_binary_hue')
```

[image]

If you have too many indicators to deal with the combinatorial explosion, explicitly making the new subsets works:

```
# Nope, need to pull out subsets:
bdata = vdata[vdata.v1 + vdata.v2 + vdata.v3 ==0.]
assert(len(bdata) > 0) # ... catch... 
bdata['Virus'] = pd.Series(['none']*len(bdata), index=bdata.index)

for i in ['v1','v2','v3']:
    on = vdata[vdata[i]==1.]
    on['Virus'] = pd.Series([i]*len(on), index=on.index)
    bdata = bdata.append(on)

j = sns.FacetGrid(bdata, col='Species', row='Virus')
j.map(plt.scatter, 'x', 'y')
j.add_legend()
j.savefig('multiple_facet_refish')
```

[image]